# committee and commitment

Tags: etymology

Why is one spelt with one **t** as in commitment where other stems of this word use two **t**'s, such as committee and similar? Is there an etymological explanation for this difference?

Answer (score 3):

Committee has a double* t because any word ending in *it* has the *t* doubled when followed by a vowel (other than ‘silent’ *e*.

Commitment* has one *t* because the *t* is followed by another consonant.  This ‘stops’ the momentum of speech so that a double *t* looks odd.

Comment: thanks for the explabation. I don't get the looking odd part yet, can you explain more?

Comment: @user2305193 Well, I have to admit that, thinking a bit more, there is an obvious exception:  some words have a ‘y’ after a single ‘t’, like ‘city’ and ‘pity’.  I would claim that the exception arises because the words are derived from (Norman) French words ‘cité’ and ‘pitié’.  By contrast, the cognate adjective from the noun ‘grit’ is ‘gritty’ with two t’s.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting because the *root word* in [Committee](https://www.etymonline.com/word/committee) and [Commitment](https://www.etymonline.com/word/commitment) is same i.e. ***[commit](https://www.etymonline.com/word/commit?ref=etymonline_crossreference)***.

The answer lies in the phonics of word **commit**. The **commit** is the C V C word i.e. Consonent-Vowel-Consonent. You can learn more about CVC words at  https://www.theschoolrun.com/cvc-words .

So, when you add a *suffix* which *begins with* **vowel** (in our case [**-ee**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ee?ref=etymonline_crossreference)), you have to **double the final consonant of the root word** (our root word is ***commit*** and it surely ends with consonant **'t'**)

> commit + -ee = committee [Root word: **commit** ends with ***consonant*** and suffix: **-ee** starts with ***vowel***]

In other case, when you add a *suffix* which *begins with* **consonant** (in this case [**-ment**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ment?ref=etymonline_crossreference)), you do not have to double the final consonant of the root word (remember our root word is ***commit***).

> commit + -ment = commitment [Root word: **commit** ends with ***consonant*** and suffix: **-ment** starts with ***consonant***]

I hope it helps!

Comment: I see, I understand this rule, is there a reason why this is beyond basically 'this is how the language is defined'

Comment: @user2305193 you can understand spelling nuances through orthography. There is a good book: [The Science of Spelling](https://www.amazon.com/Science-Spelling-Explicit-Specifics-Spellers/dp/0325007179) if you like to read.

Comment: Wanted to select this as an answer, but I have no idea why commit is supposed to be a CVC word - I guess many, many words classify as being spaced by consonant followed by vowels. As Tuffy points out in the comment section, somehow there are odd exceptions like city

Comment: @user2305193 perhaps it is due to dubious nature of letter "y". Check this oxford [video](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant). "Y" is normally treated as consonant, but sometimes acts as vowel.